# Front end, session based authentication for nginx app

Tags: nginx, authentication

I have an application that's being served by nginx. I need to put something in front of it, that:

- provides facility for managing/creation of users/passwords.
- the setting of /directory priveledges by user.
- does not require the application to be aware of authentication.
- bonus: is easy to set-up with docker-compose

This would be perfect, if it didn't need uwsgi (https://github.com/wrr/wwwhisper). There are other systems for node like passwordless and aqua (formerly drywall) that look promising, but I fear I don't have the vocabulary to describe what I'm looking for,

I realize this question is atypical and could lead to a list. So it is likely to get closed. Comments are appreciated, even if no answer exists.

Comment: Since you already know the question is going to be closed as off topic, why don't you ask it on [softwarerecs.se]?

Comment: Well, not being aware of it for one. :) Thank you. Will cross post.